# How to create a Savedforlater model in rails to store photos videos and articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User, Photo, Video, Article models. I want to have a SavedforLater model that will allow users to save various photos, videos and articles.

Comment: What is "a SavedforLater model"?

Comment: It will be a list of videos, photos and articles that they have saved, similar to a "favorites" model I suppose.

Comment: its not clear the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need a polymorphic association to accomplish this.

[Read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

After setting up your polymorphic table, you could have something like:

```
class SavedForLater < AR::Base
  belongs_to :saveable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video
  has_many :saved_videos, as: :saveable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Photo
  has_many :saved_photos, as: :saveable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Article
  has_many :saved_articles, as: :saveable, dependent: :destroy
end

class User
  has_many :saved_for_laters
end
```

Now, to save the first video you could do something like:

```
current_user.saved_for_laters.new(saveable: Video.first)
```

OR the first article

```
current_user.saved_for_laters.new(saveable: Article.first)
```

Comment: what do i add to each video to create a link to make it savable?

Comment: could you clarify the question a bit? add to each video to create a link??

Comment: If the videos are paginated and i want each video to have an icon that can be clicked and results in that video_id being added into the savedforlater database. thanks.